# How to restrict Emoji range u2600-u26FF for a text box

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I would like to restrict **Emojis** in a text box of range **u2600-u26FF** using **Regex**.

I tried this, but fails.

```
private static readonly Regex regexEmoji = new Regex(@"[\u1F600-\u1F6FF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]");
```

I would like to restric user from adding Emojis in WP8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because .NET doesn't support surrogated pairs in Regexes. You have to decompose them manually. To make it clear, a `char` in .NET is 16 bits, but `1F600` needs two `char`. So the solution is to decompose them "manually".

```
private static readonly Regex regexEmoji = new Regex(@"\uD83D[\uDE00-\uDEFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]");
```

I hope I have decomposed them correctly.

I used this site: http://www.trigeminal.com/16to32AndBack.asp

to decompose the low and the high range `\u1F600 == \uD83D \uDE00`, `\u1F6FF == \uD83D \uDEFF`. The first part of the surrogate pair is "fixed": `\uD83D`, the other is a range.

Example code (http://ideone.com/0o6qbt)

```
string str = "Hello world ☀⛿"; //  1F600 GRINNING FACE, 1F64F PERSON WITH FOLDED HANDS, 2600 BLACK SUN WITH RAYS, 26FF WHITE FLAG WITH HORIZONTAL MIDDLE BLACK STRIPE
Regex regexEmoji = new Regex(@"\uD83D[\uDE00-\uDEFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]");
MatchCollection matches = regexEmoji.Matches(str);
int count = matches.Count;
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

If you want the range `1F300-1F6FF`... it's `D83C DF00` to `D83C DFFF` and `D83D uDC00` to `D83D DEFF`

```
string str = "Hello world ☀⛿"; // 1F300 CYCLONE, 1F600 GRINNING FACE, 1F64F PERSON WITH FOLDED HANDS, 2600 BLACK SUN WITH RAYS, 26FF WHITE FLAG WITH HORIZONTAL MIDDLE BLACK STRIPE
Regex regexEmoji = new Regex(@"\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDEFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]");
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. It does not identify the emoji entered within this range.

Comment: @IshanPandya It does work here... If you copy-paste the example in a recent-enough Visual Studio on a recent-enough Windows you should see the 4 emoji that are at the extremes of your range, and the `Console.WriteLine` writes 4 matches.

Comment: Ok. So if I have to add more ranges to this solution, I just add it with an "|" sign?

Comment: @IshanPandya Yes. If they are in the `[\u0000-\uFFFF]` range then it's like your `[\u2600-\u26FF]`, otherwise ask me.

Comment: Actually I want to restrict all the emoticons which are available for windows phone. For your reference check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_in_the_Unicode_standard). The solution which you have provided works fine for U+1F600 - U+1F6FF and U+2600 - U+26FF.

Comment: @IshanPandya There is still the range `1F300-1F5FF` to be covered.

Comment: I am not sure how to that. I tried it this way but it doesn't work `@"[\uD83C[\u0000-\uDF00]-\uD83D[\u0000-\uDDFF]]|\uD83D[\uDE00-\uDEFF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]"`

Comment: @IshanPandya added the range `1F300-1F5FF`